# Regex: expression to match 'name1: A=a name2:B=b name3:C=c d'

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am using the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)'s [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile) of Python to split
`name1:A=a name2:B=b name3:C=c d`  into:

```
name1 A=a, name2 B=b, name3 C=c d
```

This is my regex for now:

```
(\w+): (A|B|C)(=[\w+\s*\w*]+)
```

But it ends up giving me the output as:

> **name1: A=a name2**: B=b **name3: C=c d**

The bold text is the text that it is capturing. The words A,B and C are from a predefined list of headings i.e. only these will occur before an `'='` sign.

Comment: which string?, add the input data to your question

Comment: 'name1 A:a name2 B:b name3 C:c d' -> is my input string. I hope am clear now. Thank you.

Comment: Yes you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) your question to add that string to make it clear for others too

Comment: This has an ambiguity due to the fact that after colon(:), the value can either be an collection of alphabets(single word), or it can be a string(words with spaces). So, differenciation between C:c d and C:c name4 is not possible.

Comment: Yes, @windstorm precisely. That is what am trying to tackle here. I basically am parsing different expressions and need some code to differentiate/filter them.

Comment: You need to determine something that differentiates between a value and key. Is it the case that key(I'm referring to name1, name2...) will always be alphanumeric. And the values can be word/space separated words but will not contain numbers? If that's the case, then you can use some logic but without regex though.

Comment: Ok @windstorm, but in my case both can be composed of  alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting you could try to match the relevant parts:

```
import re

text = "name1:A=a name2:B=b name3:C=c d"

rx = re.compile(r'\w+:(?:\w+(?:=\w+)?(?:\s+|$))+')

for match in rx.finditer(text):
    name, rest = match.group(0).split(":")
    print("{}, {}".format(name, rest))
```

This yields

```
name1, A=a 
name2, B=b 
name3, C=c d
```

See [**a demo for the expression**](https://regex101.com/r/BolI57/1) on regex101.com.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate the edge to the next match. Here line feed or end of text did the job.

```
(\w+): [ABC](=\w+\s*\w*)(?:\n|$)
```

By the way, the source contains a "," while in your regex there is a ":" used after name.

Here a solution for a one line string.

```
(\w+): (A|B|C)(=\w+\s*\w*?\(?:\s+|$))
```

Comment: Thank for pointing that out, I may have missed out. I'll do the needful changes.

Comment: @AbhibhaGupta Is your source containing line breaks as you put it in the question or is it a one line string?

Comment: It is a one line string.

Comment: @AbhibhaGupta, please edit your question in that way. thx

Comment: @AbhibhaGupta, added a solution for a one line string

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question exactly but it's good to know that you could get what you want without using regex:

```
import itertools

my_string =  "name1 A:a name2 B:b name3 C:c  d"
# split on whitespaces
split_string = my_string.split()
# get only the even elements
evens = split_string[0::2]
# get only the odd elements
odds = split_string[1::2]
# get the A=a format you want
new_odds = [odd.replace(":", "=") for odd in odds]
# zip the lists together, without losing any elements from the longer list
zipped = itertools.zip_longest(evens, new_odds)
# make this zip a list for us to view it
zipped_as_list = [x for x in zipped]
# look at what we made
print(zipped_as_list)
```

I don't know exactly what shape you want your data at the end, or how that trailing `d` is meant to be treated.

Comment: That trailing 'd' is to signify that say for field 'A' we have 'a' (can be a single word or letter)  but it can also be the case that for another field say 'C' we can have 'c d' (two letters separated by space or two words separated by space). I hope am clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! @Peaceful James. I changed the code a bit according to the new string but unfortunately its missing out the last 'd'.

Answer (score 1):

If you are limited to use split, please use below regex.

```regex
\s(?=\w+:)|:
```

**Example**

```py
import re
text="name1:A=a name2:B=b name3:C=c d"
print(re.split(r"\s(?=\w+:)|:",text))
```

**Output**

```
['name1', 'A=a', 'name2', 'B=b', 'name3', 'C=c d']
```